# Decode Raw URL in Hadoop Hive, prefer non-Java solutions

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am querying against a hive table that has a field `out_url` that has raw url encoding, like:

`http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3D260%26id%3D22`

I want to extract only the domain, and that would be possible with 
`parse_url(out_url, 'HOST') if the url was not raw-encoded.

To get around this, I'm doing this ugly double regexp replacement like:

`parse_url(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(out_url, '%3A', ':'), '%2F', '/'), 'HOST')`

that converts the `%3A` to `:` and `%2F` to `/` and then extracts the domain. I understand that I could write a Java UDF to do this, but that's not a great option for me as I currently mostly suck at writing Java.

Ideas? Is it possible to write a Python UDF?

Answer (score 12):

there seems to be an easy way here which uses Java reflection: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201109.mbox/%3C15C962F3417BF94ABEAB2314AF92A16A1FF9CE@SVR-PR-MB2.cb.careerbuilder.com%3E

```
SELECT reflect("java.net.URLDecoder", "decode", field_name) FROM table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question requested a way of doing this without writing Java.

Comment: Sorry for that. My understanding was that you didn't want to write Java, but you would agree using Java code (just one line you have to copy in your hive query).

Comment: Since all Hive functions are in Java ^^ I hope so ;-)